# Error using Action(T, object)

Tags: c#, argumentexception

I'm debugging someone else's source code, and I'm not really sure how it works, so am a bit stuck.

This code:

```
List<string> source = new List<string>();
for (int ordinal = 0; ordinal < dbDataReader.FieldCount; ++ordinal)
    source.Add(dbDataReader.GetName(ordinal));
var list = source.Select(n => new {
                                    n = n,
                                    prop = props.FirstOrDefault<DB.PropInfo<T>>((Func<DB.PropInfo<T>, bool>)(p => string.Equals(p.Name, n, StringComparison.Ordinal)))
                                    ?? props.FirstOrDefault<DB.PropInfo<T>>((Func<DB.PropInfo<T>, bool>)(p => string.Equals(p.Name, n, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                                  }
                        )
                 .Select(param0 => new { Name = param0.n, Property = param0.prop })
                 .ToList();

while (dbDataReader.Read())
{
    T instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    foreach (var data in list)
        data.Property.Setter(instance, Convert.ChangeType(dbDataReader[data.Name], data.Property.Type)); // ERROR HERE
    objList.Add(instance);
}
```

throws this exception:

> ArgumentException: Static property requires null instance, non-static property requires non-null instance.
>       Parameter name: property

The variables `instance` and `data` all have what look like valid values.

What is wrong here, please?

Comment: Seems like you're including a `static` property in your list. If it's undesired, filter it out. If it is, you need to pass `null` to the setter instead of `instance`

Comment: data.Property is of type
        private class PropInfo<T>
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public Action<T, object> Setter { get; set; }

            public Type Type { get; set; }
        }
so not static.

Comment: Passing null instead of instance yields: error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from '<null>' to 'T'

Comment: Seems like internally, your `Action<T, object>` is calling `PropertyInfo.SetValue`. Again, for a `static` property, you'll have to pass `null` instead of `instance`. How does your `Action<T, object>` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a quick dirty fix?

```
foreach (var data in list)
{
    try
    {
        data.Property.Setter(instance, Convert.ChangeType(dbDataReader[data.Name], data.Property.Type));
    }
    catch(ArgumentException e)
    {
        data.Property.Setter(default(T), Convert.ChangeType(dbDataReader[data.Name], data.Property.Type));
    }
}
```

Comment: Passing null instead of instance yields: error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from '<null>' to 'T'

Comment: You can use default(T) instead of null in a generic code.

Comment: Maybe you can add where T:class clause to the definition of generic method/class. That should allow you to use null.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the problem.
It was actually within the Setter itself - the code I was given wasn't the latest version... ;-(
Thanks for all the suggestions.